# How to open a webpage with a drop down menu that has a predetermined value based on the source link?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I'd be very grateful if someone can assist me with a puzzle I cannot find a solution for, and I thank you in advance for your patience as my html skills are very basic and I am still learning.  Normally I can find a solution on this website but this one has me stumped.

I am trying to improve a basic HTML site that has a contact form which allows the user to select a product from a drop down list and then enter their details and submit them.

Each product has its own webpage.

What I would like to do is create a link from the product page to the page that has the dropdown menu, and when that page loads, that product will automatically be selected in the dropdown menu (rather than the user having to scroll through the alphabetical list to find it).

I hope I have explained it clearly.  The drop down menu is a basic form.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Bill

**update 1**: thanks to Maykonn, I have tried to implement this but have failed.
More information here and I'm sure I'm doing something daft, please bear with me.

a) I have changed the info request webpage from stockcheck.html to stockcheck.php and it displays fine

b) on stockcheck.php I have the form code as follows

```
<select id="Name1">
<option value="Oakv">Oak veneer</option>
<option value="Oaks">Oak Solid</option>
<option value="Walnutv">Walnut veneer</option>
<option value="Walnuts">Walnut solid</option>
<option value="Willow">Willow</option>
</select>
```

(this is heavily trimmed down, there's lots of items in the list)

c) I then inserted the script you gave me (I tried in different places too)

```
<script>
document.getElementById('Name1').value = '<?php echo $_GET['product']; ?>';
</script>
```

d) I then went to the product page (in this case Willow) and put this simple line

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/stockcheck.php?product=Willow">click here to check if we have the Willow chair in stock</a>
```

Surely I'm making a simple mistake, but I Just can't find it.  Thank you for responding.

Comment: The only way to retain a value from one page to the next is by server side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking to contact.html (or what you called it), change contact.html to contact.php (which allows server-side scripting (in this case PHP)) and then link to `contact.php?product=ID` where id is the value the product has in the dropdown of your contact form.

Insert this javascript+php code snippet to be run after body has loaded:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('DROPDOWN ID').value = '<?php echo $_GET['product']; ?>';
</script>
```

So if you have:

```
<select id="test">
  <option value="product1">Cake</option>
  <option value="product2">Mushrooms</option>
  <option value="product3">Ice Cream</option>
  <option value="product7">More cake</option>
</select>
```

For your dropdown you would set 'DROPDOWN' ID to 'test' and when you want Ice Cream as default you link to 'contact.php?product=product3'

I hope it makes sense.

**EDIT**

I forgot to tell you that you should definitely only run that javascript IF ?product=... is defined, but that story is not directly related to your current question, so I left that part out.